# Problema con archivo de text y PHP

Tags: php, text

Archivos de texto y PHP: Cómo hago para que automáticamente muestre el mensaje que acabo de enviar por POST en la misma página?

aquí esta mi código:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>mboard</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$myfile = fopen("mboard.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");

if (filesize("mboard.txt") > 0) {
echo fread($myfile,filesize("mboard.txt"));
} else { 
echo "empty file!";
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {

$txt= $_POST["text-mboard"];

fwrite($myfile, $txt);

echo fread($myfile,filesize("mboard.txt"));

};

if ($_POST) {
echo fread($myfile,filesize("mboard.txt"));
};

?> 

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="text-mboard">
</form>

<?php fclose($myfile); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: y cual es el error que te sale por pantalla??

Comment: no sale error, sino que no se actualiza el archivo automatticamente, tengo q cargar de nuevo la página para que muestre el último texto ingresado al archivo de texto

Comment: con enter, o podría poner un boton submit

Comment: en ese caso tienes que hacer uso de ajax, para que el envio tenga un resultado tambien y al refrescar te muestre el nuevo texto... si lo haces de html a php directo tendras que hacer el refresco manual con F5

Comment: y separas el php del html si es posible te ayudara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personalmente creo que utilizar fread y fwrite es matar moscas a cañonazos, ya que es para lectura de ficheros binarios.

Por otra parte tenías dos fread, tanto si te habían enviado algo como si no, que he eliminado.

```
<?php

$filename = "mboard.txt";

$myfile = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to open file!");

if ( $myfile == '' ) {
   echo "empty file!";
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {

   $txt= $_POST["text-mboard"];

   file_put_contents($filename, $txt, FILE_APPEND);

   echo file_get_contents($filename);

};
?> 

<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="text-mboard">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```